# Any way to handle water/drain lines crossing a vent pipe?

Tags: plumbing

[image: Guest bathroom waterlines crossing the vent]

We're upgrading from a single sink to a double sink in our guest bathroom which is on the first floor. It is on an exterior wall (2x6). A vent pipe from the ground floor toilet is running in the way of where I need to add the water lines and drain for the second sink. Does anyone have any solution on how to handle this situation where the vent and water/drain lines need to cross each other?

Comment: The water lines are trivial, since you seem to have PEX and PEX flexes. For the drain, outside the wall is the way. If the sink drains are less than 30 inches apart you can just join them before the trap. If more than 30 inches you need two traps.

Answer (score 3):

Bring the pipes across in the cabinet holding the sinks, rather than in the wall.

As @ecnerwal pointed out, "If the sink drains are less than 30 inches apart you can just join them before the trap. If more than 30 inches you need two traps."